# Add new systemd unit file directory

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm working on an embedded system which mounts /etc as read-only, I'd like to add a new, additional directory in which I can add/modify systemd unit files.

So for example:

```
/mnt/flash/test/myservice.service
```

systemctl daemon-reload

How can I configure the /mnt/flash/test/ path to be searched by systemctl daemon-reload?

Thanks!

Comment: Use an overlay filesystem instead. This is what everyone else does.

Comment: That's kind of a big change, I found that /run/systemd/system/ can be used for runtime drop-ins and just linked my files there. Seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I found that /run/systemd/system/ can be used for runtime drop-ins and just linked my files there. Seems to work